# Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) on my array code

Tags: java, arrays

I'm learning programming and I was working on arrays, but in this method (which is in a class) for some reason when it compiles it shows me a "Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" message.

This is the code:

```
    public int[] ByN(int[] vector){
      int Blancas = 0;
      int Negras = 0;
      int[] ByN = new int[2];
      combinacion temporal = new combinacion(tamlog);

      temporal.copiar(vec);

      for (int i = 0; i < tamfisico; i++){
        int j = 0;
        Boolean Tof=false;

        While ((ToF == false) && (j < tamfisico);){
          if (vector[i] == temporal[j]){
             Blancas ++;
             temporal.borrar(j);
             j--;
             t--;
             ToF= true;
          }
          j++;
         }
      }


      for (int i = 0; i < tamlog; i++){
        if (vec[i]== vector[i])
          Negras++;
     }
      Blancas = Blancas - Negras;
      ByN[0]= Blancas;
      ByN[1] = Negras;
      return ByN;
     }
```

It is meant to consider 2 int arrays and count how many are in both - how many are in the exact same position.

The problem seems to be in the first for not sure why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
While ((ToF == false) && (j < tamfisico);){
```

to

```
while ((ToF == false) && (j < tamfisico)){
```

(lowercase `while` and no semicolon)

Answer (score 0):

When i went through your code, i had found following mistakes that you had done. Java is using "camelCase" naming conversion pattern.

1. first letter of a variabel can not be capital letter

   int Blancas = 0;  -----> int balance

   int Negras = 0;   -----> int negras
2. first letter of a method can not be capital letter

   public int[] ByN(int[] vector) -----> public int[] byN(int[] vector)
3. first letter of a class should be a capital letter

   combinacion temporal = new combinacion(tamlog); -----> Combinacion temporal = new Combinacion(tamlog);
4. start letter of the "While" word should be simple like "while"

Additionally,

" While ((ToF == false) && (j < tamfisico);) " should be change as " while ((ToF == false) && (j < tamfisico))"

Replace "w" letter and remove ; from the statement.

Good Luck !!!